# Почему градиент с переходом в прозрачный цвет создаёт черноту?

Tags: css, svg

Есть два градиентных круга, в одном я переход делаю к прозрачному цвету `transparent`, в другом к тому же цвету, что и фон `pink`.

Я ожидал что результат будет одинаковый, а он разный, более того, если присмотреться то при переходе в прозрачный цвет наблюдается чернота. Почему так?

**Что мне надо.**

Я хочу сгенерировать фон из цветных пятен-кругов, которые градиентно исчезают.

Но если я делаю переход в `transparent` то там куча черноты получается, что мне не подходит. А выбрать фиксированный цвет куда переходит градиент я не могу, так как пятна генерируются на случайном месте, и в случае фиксированного крайнего цвета они будут перекрывать друг друга, что можно посмотреть на втором блоке примера, а мне надо что бы они просвечивали. На первом блоке они просвечивают, но там появилась чернота.

Как это можно сделать и можно ли вообще?

```html
<svg style="background-color: pink; width:500px; height:350px;">
  <g>
    <radialGradient id="grad1">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"></stop>
                <stop offset="15%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
                <stop offset="40%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" fill="url(#grad1)"></circle>
  </g>
  <g>
    <radialGradient id="grad2">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"></stop>
                <stop offset="15%" stop-color="green"></stop>
                <stop offset="40%" stop-color="green"></stop>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    <circle cx="140" cy="220" r="100" fill="url(#grad2)"></circle>
  </g>
  <g>
    <radialGradient id="grad3">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"></stop>
                <stop offset="15%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
                <stop offset="40%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="pink"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    <circle cx="350" cy="110" r="100" fill="url(#grad3)"></circle>
  </g>
  <g>
    <radialGradient id="grad4">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"></stop>
                <stop offset="15%" stop-color="green"></stop>
                <stop offset="40%" stop-color="green"></stop>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="pink"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    <circle cx="380" cy="220" r="100" fill="url(#grad4)"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно исправить с помощью `stop-opacity`.
*Color* `transparent` меняем на `blue`, а дальше контролируем прозрачность с помощью `stop-opacity`:

```css
svg {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version="1.1" width="200" height="200">   
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="radial">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1.0"/>
      <stop offset="15%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="0.3"/>
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="0.25"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#radial)"/>
</svg>
```